# in SQL, what is the right way to detect ASCII zero characters in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

What is the right way to detect ascii zero characters?

I'm perplexed that in my example query a plain charindex call doesn't find it in the string.

Well, unless I manipulate it. For example by reversing the string, or chopping it to the last character...

This happens whether it is a trailing or interior character, but not when it is the initial character.

I need to do this to reliably eliminate them.

It's something to do with unicode because a strictly varchar variant of this does work correctly.

My example:

```
declare @testval as nvarchar(max) = N'abcde' + nchar(0)

select
    charindex(char(0), @testval) where_is_char0
    , charindex(nchar(0), @testval) where_is_nchar0
    , charindex(nchar(0), reverse(@testval)) where_is_reversed_nchar0
    , charindex(nchar(0), right(@testval, 1)) where_is_lastchar_nchar0
```

Here are the results:

```
where_is_char0       where_is_nchar0      where_is_reversed_nchar0 where_is_lastchar_nchar0
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------------ ------------------------
0                    0                    1                        1
```

Comment: When you say eliminate them, do you want to remove from the source data or just find rows that contain char(0)? Note you cannot have char *and* nchar in the *same* variable - if you define it as nvarchar then it's... nvarchar

Comment: Use a binary collation: `charindex(char(0), @testval COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2)`. Note that this works for both `CHAR` and `NCHAR` types.

Comment: I like this - works for me.

Answer (score 1):

[CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) docs say:

> 0x0000 (char(0)) is an undefined character in Windows collations and
> cannot be included in CHARINDEX.

You can convert your `nvarchar` string to `varbinary` and search for binary value.

```
declare @testval as nvarchar(max) = N'abcde' + nchar(0)

declare @bin_testval as varbinary(max) = CAST(@testval as varbinary(max));

select
    charindex(0x0000, @bin_testval) where_is_char0
    ,@bin_testval AS BinaryValue
;
```

**Result**

```
+----------------+----------------------------+
| where_is_char0 |        BinaryValue         |
+----------------+----------------------------+
|             10 | 0x610062006300640065000000 |
+----------------+----------------------------+
```

Keep in mind that `nvarchar` is unicode 2 bytes per character, so position of `0x0000` in the original string is not 10, but twice less.

Comment: This approach is not correct: it's possible for a string to contain a sequence of two 0 bytes without containing a NUL character, when represented as UCS-2. For example, try `declare @testval as nvarchar(max) = N'a䀀'`, which contains `U+4000 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH 4000`. The docs are actually also incorrect when they say `CHAR(0)` cannot be used in `CHARINDEX` -- this is true *for Windows collations*, but not binary ones, when the statement makes it appear as if it can never be used.